# How can I create my own comparator for a map?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

```
typedef map<string, string> myMap;
```

When inserting a new pair to `myMap`, it will use the key `string` to compare by its own string comparator. Is it possible to override that comparator? For example, I'd like to compare the key `string` by its length, not by the alphabet. Or is there any other way to sort the map?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

`std::map` takes up to four template type arguments, the third one being a comparator. E.g.:

```
struct cmpByStringLength {
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
        return a.length() < b.length();
    }
};

// ...
std::map<std::string, std::string, cmpByStringLength> myMap;
```

Alternatively you could also pass a comparator to [`map`s constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/).

Note however that when comparing by length you can only have one string of each length in the map as a key.

Comment: note that we can use multimap if we want to contain duplicated key

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche any chance you you provide an example of passing comparitor to constructor?

Comment: @bpeikes: It doesn't look too different: `std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap(cmpByStringLength());`

Comment: I had a problem with a std::map<int, int>, some with increasing order and others by decreasing order. I didn't want to use std::map<int, int, std::greater> and std::map<int, int, std::less> because then I couldn't use maps which were sorted in different orders as parameters to a single function unless I made everything a template. I found that I had to do the following:
typedef std::map<int, int, (bool)*(int, int)> mymap;
Then I was able to pass in functions.

I tried the following, but it wouldn't work:
typedef std::map<int, int> mymap;

mymap map1(std::less);
mymap map2(std::greater);

Comment: That would be `std::map<int,int> m(std::less());` - note the parantheses. You definitely don't need function pointers. If you run into problems, best ask a new question about that.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: That won't work for passing the comparator to the constructor, as the constructor argument must be an instance of the comparator type, and `cmpByStringLength` is not an instance of `std::less<std::string>`.  For a general map that can have any comparator set in the constructor, you need something like `std::map<std::string, std::string, std::function<bool(const std::string &, const std::string &)>> myMap(cmpByStringLength);`

Comment: if using map this way, will the order of length of strings be maintained if we are inserting string dynamically?

Comment: I think in C++20, you can use lambda function as well as functor.

Answer (score 41):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparator struct:

```
auto comp = [](const string& a, const string& b) { return a.length() < b.length(); };
map<string, string, decltype(comp)> my_map(comp);

my_map["1"]      = "a";
my_map["three"]  = "b";
my_map["two"]    = "c";
my_map["fouuur"] = "d";

for(auto const &kv : my_map)
    cout << kv.first << endl;
```

Output:

> 1
>   two
>   three
>   fouuur

I'd like to repeat the final note of Georg's answer: When comparing by length you can only have one string of each length in the map as a key.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/V0Afrt)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the 3rd template parameter on `map` specifies the comparator, which is a binary predicate.  Example:

```
struct ByLength : public std::binary_function<string, string, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const string& lhs, const string& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.length() < rhs.length();
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef map<string, string, ByLength> lenmap;
    lenmap mymap;

    mymap["one"] = "one";
    mymap["a"] = "a";
    mymap["fewbahr"] = "foobar";

    for( lenmap::const_iterator it = mymap.begin(), end = mymap.end(); it != end; ++it )
        cout << it->first << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why the derive from `std::binary_function`? Is it needed?

Comment: `std::binary_function` is removed in c++17 so this answer could probably use updating.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the type of the pointer to your comparison function as the 3rd type into the map, and provide the function pointer to the map constructor:
`map<keyType, valueType, typeOfPointerToFunction> mapName(pointerToComparisonFunction);`

Take a look at the example below for providing a comparison function to a `map`, with `vector` iterator as key and `int` as value.

```
#include "headers.h"

bool int_vector_iter_comp(const vector<int>::iterator iter1, const vector<int>::iterator iter2) {
    return *iter1 < *iter2;
}

int main() {
    // Without providing custom comparison function
    map<vector<int>::iterator, int> default_comparison;

    // Providing custom comparison function
    // Basic version
    map<vector<int>::iterator, int,
        bool (*)(const vector<int>::iterator iter1, const vector<int>::iterator iter2)>
        basic(int_vector_iter_comp);

    // use decltype
    map<vector<int>::iterator, int, decltype(int_vector_iter_comp)*> with_decltype(&int_vector_iter_comp);

    // Use type alias or using
    typedef bool my_predicate(const vector<int>::iterator iter1, const vector<int>::iterator iter2);
    map<vector<int>::iterator, int, my_predicate*> with_typedef(&int_vector_iter_comp);

    using my_predicate_pointer_type = bool (*)(const vector<int>::iterator iter1, const vector<int>::iterator iter2);
    map<vector<int>::iterator, int, my_predicate_pointer_type> with_using(&int_vector_iter_comp);


    // Testing 
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};

    default_comparison.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.end(), 0}));
    default_comparison.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 0}));
    default_comparison.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 1}));
    default_comparison.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin() + 1, 1}));

    cout << "size: " << default_comparison.size() << endl;
    for (auto& p : default_comparison) {
        cout << *(p.first) << ": " << p.second << endl;
    }

    basic.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.end(), 0}));
    basic.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 0}));
    basic.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 1}));
    basic.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin() + 1, 1}));

    cout << "size: " << basic.size() << endl;
    for (auto& p : basic) {
        cout << *(p.first) << ": " << p.second << endl;
    }

    with_decltype.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.end(), 0}));
    with_decltype.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 0}));
    with_decltype.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 1}));
    with_decltype.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin() + 1, 1}));

    cout << "size: " << with_decltype.size() << endl;
    for (auto& p : with_decltype) {
        cout << *(p.first) << ": " << p.second << endl;
    }

    with_typedef.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.end(), 0}));
    with_typedef.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 0}));
    with_typedef.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin(), 1}));
    with_typedef.insert(pair<vector<int>::iterator, int>({v.begin() + 1, 1}));

    cout << "size: " << with_typedef.size() << endl;
    for (auto& p : with_typedef) {
        cout << *(p.first) << ": " << p.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: this `decltype(int_vector_iter_comp)*` is brilliant !  thank you!!