# std::map issue while auto sorting string as key

Tags: stdmap

I am using std::map to add values

```
std::map<CString,int>
```

the follwing is the list of items to be inserted as Key

- X_1O1
- X_101_A
- X_70
- X_67

I was expecting a sorted map with

- X_67
- X_70
- X_101
- X_101_A

but i am getting the result as

- X_101
- X_101_A
- X_67
- X_70

is there a way that I can sort the keys properly in the map?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5733353/987632)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create an own comparator for map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733254/create-an-own-comparator-for-map)