# Can't i find Keyvalue of map container TCHAR* using TCHAR[]?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namesapce std;
void main()
{
   map<const TCHAR*, int> Map;
   Map.insert(make_pare(L"DOG1",1));
   Map.insert(make_pare(L"DOG2",2));

   TCHAR szTem[128];
   wsprintf(szTem,L"DOG%d",1);

   map<const TCHAR*, int>::iterator iter = Map.find(szTem);

   cout << iter->second << endl;
}
```

Like this case, I couldn't find TCHAR* Keyvalue using TCHAR[]. 
Why i can't do this, and how can i find pointer string Keyvalue using string that include integer fomula?

Comment: because the comparison operator `<` isn't defined for TCHAR* to dereference the pointer and compare string values, it's going to compare the pointer address values which is incorrect. You need to define the comparator or use `std::string` is there a reason you need to use `TCHAR` here?

Comment: You didn't define `TCHAR`. If you use non-standard features, you should tell us which os/compiler/standard library you are targetting. `void main` is not standard either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that, because default `map` comparator will compare `TCHAR` pointers, which of course would be different. Best approach would be to use `std::wstring` instead. If you insist on using `TCHAR` pointer, you have to provide [custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733254/create-an-own-comparator-for-map).

Comment: What if `TCHAR` isn't `wchar_t`?

Comment: Then use `std::string`, or define a macro in case you need to support *both* kinds of strings.

Comment: You don't need a macro. Simply use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` to support any `TCHAR`.