# How does std map know to use std string's data as key

Tags: c++, stl

So if you create a map with a class as the key.  Then the keys are pointers to classes?

If `std::string` is a class, how does it manage to use character array data as keys in the map??

So the comparator can make 2 'different' class instances appear equal because their 'strings' match? If you confirm this, I shall mark your answer.

Comment: No, keys are not pointers to classes, unless you make a map that uses `string*` keys (a bad idea). Map uses operator implementation for `<` to compare keys.

Comment: Do you mean a class like `class Foo{ int val; std::string s}`, and then only comparing the values  of `s` to sort? Some sample code would make the question much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The key itself is stored in a `std::map`. So if you have a class called `Foo` then an instance of `Foo` is stored in the map.

Whether you use `Foo` or `std::string` as the key doesn't matter to the `std::map`. What does matter is that there is a [comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733353/1460794) defined so that the `std::map` can know how to sort the classes as keys.

Comment: Maybe you can update your answer slightly, and i will choose it.