# std::map use. What is wrong here ? core dump ? What I do not do correctly?

Tags: c++

What is wrong here ? core dump ? What I do not do correctly?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

bool compFloats (const float f1, const float f2){
  return floor (f1) < floor (f2);
};

int main (int argc, char **argv){

  std::map < float, char, decltype (&compFloats) > m;


  m.emplace (3.9, 'a');
  m.emplace (3.1, 'b');
  m.emplace (4.1, 'c');
  m.emplace (4.5, 'd');
  m.emplace (5.2, 'e');

  for (auto i = m.begin (); i != m.end (); i++)
    printf ("%c ", i->second);
  printf ("\n");


  printf ("hello world\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could have  been a little more curious and removed the third template argument in your `map` declaration to see if the results change.

Comment: There is any syntax error, or logic one ? it dumps at the second execution of emplace.

Comment: Well, do as I stated.  Remove the third template argument, rebuild / rerun your application.  If it doesn't crash, then maybe add more to your question as to what you observed?  You're getting close to having a downvote due to "lack of research".

Comment: When the third argument is taken off the comparison is different and the program works.

Comment: Now that you've done that, this should have all been done before you posted.  Then in the question, you could have stated "when I remove the third parameter, my program no longer crashes.  What is in the third parameter that would cause this?".  That would have been a much better way to present the question, not as you originally had done.

Comment: in that Q&A the third argument is a class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733254/how-can-i-create-my-own-comparator-for-a-map. And removing this argument probably does the same thing as your code is trying to do since you're just comparing floats in a natural way.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the assumption that your custom-built comparison operator is necessary for this code to function, the issue you're facing is that the argument being passed to the map template, `decltype (&compFloats)`, doesn't describe the specific function you want to use as a comparator, but rather the typename of that function. As a result, when the map attempts to perform comparisons, it doesn't have any concrete function to use, and probably dereferences a null pointer somewhere, causing the core dump.

If you actually need this kind of comparison (where the floating point values are being rounded down to the nearest integer before being saved), you'll need to define the map like this instead, using a local `struct` that can compare `float`s together:

```
struct CompFloat {
    bool operator()(float a, float b) const {
        return floor(a) < floor(b);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<float, char, CompFloat> m;
    //...
}
```

Alternatively, if what you need is just to use a `std::map` with `float`s as the key, and the truncation is immaterial (or unnecessary/unhelpful), just write this instead.

```
int main() {
    std::map<float, char> m;
    //...
}
```

This will do what you probably expect of it.

Comment: `std::map < float, char, decltype (&compFloats) > m(compFloats);` - problem solved.

Comment: @LogicStuff If you prefer that as a solution, you're welcome to post it yourself as a self-answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the preliminary indications of @Xirema I tried an "expected syntax"

instead of:

```
std::map < float, char, decltype (&compFloats) > m;
```

I initialized it as:

```
std::map<float,char,decltype(&floatComp)> m(&floatComp);
```

I don't know where in the documents it is written but now works correctly as expected !!!

Answer (score 0):

The code to understand better the difference between class and object of a map follows by defining two maps with the same type but different comparison functions.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

bool comp1(const float f1,const float f2)   {return floor(f1)<floor(f2);}
bool comp2(const float f1,const float f2) {return f1-floor(f1)<f2-floor(f2);}

typedef bool (*comp_t)(const float,const float);
typedef std::map<float,char,comp_t> M;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
        M m1(&comp1);
        M m2(&comp2);

        m1.emplace(3.9,'a');m2.emplace(3.9,'a');
        m1.emplace(3.1,'b');m2.emplace(3.1,'b');
        m1.emplace(4.1,'c');m2.emplace(4.1,'c');
        m1.emplace(4.5,'d');m2.emplace(4.5,'d');
        m1.emplace(5.2,'e');m2.emplace(5.2,'e');

    for (auto i=m1.begin();i!=m1.end();i++)
        printf("%c ",i->second);
    printf("\n");

    for (auto i=m2.begin();i!=m2.end();i++)
        printf("%c ",i->second);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```