# The custom comparator for map does not work for inserting and finding

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, llvm, llvm-ir

I implemented a custom comparator for a map, but it seems not to work for inserting elements and finding keys.

**Addition**: I wonder if it is related to the implementation of STL. Since map::key_comp returns false reflexively for the two keys, which means they are equal, but map::find can find only one of them. This does not meet the specification of STL.

I tried to compare whether two function types are the same since I used function types as map's keys. The key point is to identify identical structures with different suffixes.

Therefore, I wrote this custom comparator. `isTypeEqual` is a static function.

```cpp
struct cmp_func_type {
    bool operator()(FunctionType* a, FunctionType* b) {
        if (a->getNumParams() == b->getNumParams()) {
            if (isTypeEqual(a->getReturnType(), b->getReturnType())) {
                for (unsigned i = 0; i < a->getNumParams(); ++i) {
                    if (!isTypeEqual(a->getParamType(i), b->getParamType(i))) {
                        return a < b;
                    }
                }
                return false; // They are equal
            }
        }
        return a < b;
    }
};
```

In results, I found there are two types that should be equal according to my algorithm, but they seem not to share the same key. One is `i32 (%struct.nvkm_bios.100694*, i8*, i32, i16)`, the other one is `i32 (%struct.nvkm_bios*, i8*, i32, i16)`.

I used `cmp_func_type()(a, b)` and `cmp_func_type()(b, a)` to test the result, they all returned false.

Then I assigned a value to type `a` then used `map.find(a)` and `map.find(b)` to check whether they mapped to the same value. But only `a` could be found.

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare the *pointers*? Unrelated pointers (like pointers to two different objects) doesn't really have any comparable relationship.

Comment: agree with @Someprogrammerdude.  Please look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733254/how-can-i-create-my-own-comparator-for-a-map).

Comment: Normally, in LLVM IR, the identical types share the same pointer and different types have different pointers. So the pointers are comparable.

Comment: An exception here is that, because of the different suffixes, the identical types may have different pointers. That's why I need to implement a custom comparator here.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clearer, but for possible unrelated pointers the only sensible comparisons are really for equality or inequality. Comparing less-than or greater-than doesn't make sense generally. What does it mean that a pointer is "greater" than the other?

Comment: And are you sure that your function satisfies the [compare requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), including [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)?

Comment: Unless all the pointers are pointing into the same array you are in Unspecified Behaviour land. See example ending with `assert(f(&x, &y) == f(&x, &y)); // may fire in a conforming implementation` from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

Comment: And to nitpick a little, does it make sense to have ordering between "types"? Perhaps an unordered container (like `std::unordered_map`) would make more sense?

Comment: In my experience, pointers' address represents their declaration order in the file. The type which is declared earlier has a smaller pointer address.

Comment: @Lesterth Regarding declaration order, that's a very implementation specific detail, and doesn't hold up really. It's not uncommon that local variables have reversed that. And it all falls apart when you use dynamic allocation of objects. I think the bigger question for you is: Why do you need the types to be ordered to begin with? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: These pointers are not local variables and will not change until the end of the program. They have a determined order after loading the file. In fact, I do not need ordered pointers, I just want to utilize map with a FunctionType* key. The problem is that the map does not identify the identical keys as my comparator expected.

Comment: Then your comparator probably doesn't follow the requirements I linked to above. Perhaps it would be easier to not use ordered containers if you don't really need it (especially considering all the problems there is with ordering of unrelated pointers, no matter what you think about it).

Comment: I have tried unordered_map but the result remains the same. `cmp_func_type` returns true when comparing two types but they still do not map to the same value.

Comment: @someprogrammer there are two type systems at play. LLVM defines types, and so does C++. LLVM types are objects in C++, and LLVM types can be equality-tested by testing pointer equality in C++. What Lesterth wants to do makes sense for an LLVM frontend. I'll try an answer later today.

Comment: I think the key point is that how does map find a key. In my opinion, when the comparator all returns false for a < b and b < a, it means a and b are the same key. But that seems not to be true.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't have time for an answer. A hint though: Mixing C++ pointer comparison with LLVM type comparison sounds like a trouble magnet; try changing your isTypeEquall() into something like ulong getTypeKey() that returns the same value if two types are equal and different if different, and use that as map key. Don't sort on pointer values sometimes and on contents sometimes.

Comment: You say that identical types may be represented by unequal pointers. Suppose pointers `A` and `B` represent such identical types; `A < B`, but your comparator declares them equivalent, so `cmp(A, B) == false`. There may exist an unrelated type, represented by a pointer `C`, such that `A < C && C < B`. In this case, your comparator is not transitive, and therefore doesn't satisfy *strict weak ordering* requirements, and therefore using it with `std::map` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @RichardCritten While it's true that normal less-than operator is only defined on pointers into the same array, the approach could be salvaged by using `std::less` instead; it is required to induce a total order on all pointers of the same type.

Comment: But if A and B are identical types, only one of them can exist in the map as a key. Therefore, C will compare with only one of them. Furthermore, the main problem is A and B are not regarded as equal by map, although the comparator returns false reflexively.