# C++ how to define custom key in map(It's a little different from similar problems)?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to define a map like:

```
#include<map>
struct key{
    vector<int> start_idx;
    vector<int> len;
};

map<key, int> m;
```

I looked at other questions and found that I could write the comparison function like this

```
struct Class1Compare
{
   bool operator() (const key1& lhs, const key2& rhs) const
   {
       .....
   }
};
```

In fact, start_idx means a start index in a file, len means length, so I need to use other parameter in the comparsion function like:

```
bool operator() (const key1& lhs, const key2& rhs) const
{
    ... //in this field, i can use (char *file).
}
```

and char *file may not be global, because I use multi-thread which means in different thread, char *file is different.

Comment: Do you want to read a file inside a comparator? It's hardly a good idea.

Comment: This looks like a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/), perhaps also specify what your goal is. That way you can find the best solution.

Comment: Your comparator can keep a reference to the file. But then everyone of your `map<key,int>` instances can be different when they reference different files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create my own comparator for a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733254/how-can-i-create-my-own-comparator-for-a-map)

Comment: I am so sorry for my poor English ability to describe the problem and thanks for following my question.  The answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have data members in you comparer.

```
struct Class1Compare
{
    bool operator() (const key1& lhs, const key2& rhs) const
    {
        // uses lhs, rhs and file
    }
    char * file;
};
```

Your map will require a non-default constructed `Class1Compare`.

```
char * file = /* some value */
map<key, int, Class1Compare> m({ file });
key k = /* key's data relating to file */
m[k] = 42;
```